# AWS Cloudformation template storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, aws-cloudformation

We currently have a number of resources deployed to an AWS dev and prod account. These include lambda functions, kinesis streams, dynamo db tables and RDS instances. Some of these resources are deployed using our ci tool and cloudformation and some are done manually. For a number of reasons we want to have everything defined in cloudformation. Most of the resources are part of a larger system or stack. I.e an api gateway connected to a lambda function which might consume a kinesis stream which is populated by another lambda function. The question is, in this scenario where should the cloudformation template live? In the repo for the first lambda? The second lambda? A central cloudformation repo or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

Best practice I've seen is to develop/commit your template to a source code repository (Git usually) and then leverage a CI tool (like Jenkins, Travis CI, Bamboo, etc) to copy those to an S3 bucket which your accounts have permissions to read (NOT PUBLIC). Reference all templates from their S3 URL and keep those URLs up to date with your CI tool.

For example, `master` branches end up at `http://bucket-name-here.s3.amazonaws.com/project-name/template.json` and `develop` branch ends up at `http://bucket-name-here.s3.amazonaws.com/project-name/template-develop.json`. You could expand feature/release branches to follow `http://bucket-name-here.s3.amazonaws.com/project-name/template-release-v1.0.json` or similar.

When you reference these in your other resources you'll always go against whatever code level you want (reference `template.json` for the production-level code).

Comment: Thanks..but in a stack which consists of several lambda functions which code repo would the template live in?

Answer (score 2):

Storing the templates in any source control is a great start to get the benefits of centralizing and versioning the code.

*However*, if you are investing in automating primarily in the AWS cloud you should look at storing your templates (and other code) in **[AWS CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/welcome.html)** git service.

The main reasons and benefits of this are:

- tight integration options with other AWS services
- triggers for events on repo action like pull requests and commits that send SNS notifications or trigger Lambda actions.
- ability to share repo access with developers and other services and applications using IAM policies and roles.

CodeCommit gives a really fine grained and safe way to separate who can do what, and what applications have access to repo's so you can segment production and staging environments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We are pretty heavily invested in gitlab for our source control but could consider it for cloudformation stuff. Again though, where I've got multiple lambdas in one stack which lambda does the template live with?

Comment: Even in that case I would keep the cloudformation templates centralized in CodeCommit, you can have actions that sync the templates back to your gitlab repo's if needed. From CC it's easy to give your lambda's access to the templates using IAM and the triggers can really help in automating the CI/CD processes.

Answer (score 0):

We have all source code in GitLab with heavy Jenkins CI/CD environment. And considering to add pipeline step to trigger AWS CodeCommit+CodePipeline to pull from dedicated GitLab repos to execute CloudFormation templates in Amazon dedicated way with all benefits.